# Powershell last bootup time of computer showing two different outputs

Tags: powershell, time, output

```
$OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername c83323

($OSInfo `
    | Format-List `
        @{Name="OS Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}} `
    | Out-String).Trim() #Output OS Name, Boot Time, and Install Date
```

> output --> OS Boot Time : 12/6/2016 4:09:20 PM

```
$osinfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername c83323
    $osinfo.ConvertToDateTime($osinfo.LastBootUpTime)
```

> output --> Tuesday, December 06, 2016 4:09:20 PM

Why is it when I run the first set, I get time in one way, but when I run it the 2nd way, I get it in a completely different format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of your second instance will be in **DateTime** type. This format depends on the datetime format you have Choosen on your system. 
I modified your code to get the type:

```
$osinfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem; ($osinfo.ConvertToDateTime($osinfo.LastBootUpTime)).GetType()
```

But in your first instance, you use something called a  **calculated property** [(check this link)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) , which basically let you "Format" and display attributes in the way you prefer. In your case, thru the expression you have provided your date and time had converted into an array and hence it lost its format.

Get type:

```
($OSInfo | Format-List @{Name="OS Boot Time";Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}).GetType()
```

The above type would be an **array**.

**EDIT:**

Below snippet should do the trick!

```
@("Computer1","Computer2") | foreach { 
    $OSInfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem -computername $_;
    "Boot time for Computer: $_ = " + $OSInfo.ConvertToDateTime($OSInfo.LastBootUpTime);    
} | Out-File "C:\thefolderYouPrefer\boottime.txt"
```

Comment: Is there a way to store into a variable, the calculated property of the first example..without having a header in there? I want to get the boot time of many computers and store it in a text file and it does no good with a header each time.

Comment: $osinfo = get-wmiobject -class win32_operatingsystem; $osinfo.ConvertToDateTime($osinfo.LastBootUpTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") for your previous request..

Comment: Updated the answer with snippet for your need!! See if that helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using `Format-List` and/or `Out-String` in the first case. When using these, PowerShell formats the DateTime object's output, just as if you wrote this:

```
"$(Get-Date)"
```